# Get underlying non-aliased table from aliased table in jOOQ

Tags: jooq

I have an aliased table

`Author a = AUTHOR.as("a");`

and I'm trying to access the underlying table `AUTHOR` from `a` but cant see how to.

I've tried `a.alias.wrapped` but that doesn't work for me

Comment: There's no such public API. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: I want to check if my alias table is an instance of `AUTHOR` and then do something if so

Comment: I solved my issue by doing a test for `(is Author)` instead of checking for the underlying table  `== AUTHOR`

Comment: Great to hear! Note: You can answer your own question here on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying table is not exposed via the Aliased table and so you can't get it.

Instead if trying to get check if the Aliased table is a certain type (which was the original reason I wanted the underlying table) you can do

```
if (a is Author) {
 // Do Something
}
```